# Error while running a shell script : "pipe call failed"

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, sh

I am executing a shell script in an infinte loop. Script is meant to get the connected devices. But when it runs for some time, it will stop executing after displaying an error message `pipe call failed`.

This is the line where I am getting this error

```
arp -n -i eth1 | grep "?" | awk '{print $4}' > out.txt
```

Am I doing anything wrong in redirecting this output to a file? Is there a way to handle file descriptors in a shell script?

EDIT: Here is my script

```
HOME_NETWORK_INTERFACE=eth1
echo "Generating list of MoCA device MACs..."
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "Error! Insufficient arguments. Format is $0 <output file path>"
        exit 1
fi
arp -n -i $HOME_NETWORK_INTERFACE | grep "?" | awk '{print $4}' > $1
echo "Done"
```

EDIT :

I found that this issue is due to the usage of "system" command in cpp application. If this script is executed using "system", say 1000 times, i will get this error. Does any one have any idea about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think `grep` throws a syntax error for that, but you might want to fix the [useless use of `grep`(http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep); `arp | awk '/\?/{ print $4 }'`

Comment: `pipe call failed` sounds more like an internal system error, rather than something directly related to your script. Can you post more of the script for context, though? The line you post looks fine.

Comment: By calling `system()` you are forking a child process. Whenever a child process is forked, the system tries to duplicate the parent memory to the child memory. If you attempt to fork a child process 1000 times, the memoery might have not been released to the system yet and therefore the system will think that the parent process has bigger memory that it really was using, You are running out of memory according to the memory accountant. You can set your limits and set memory overcommit to 2. However overcommitment is not really a good idea.

Comment: system() executes a command-interpreter, i.e. a shell, which is slower than a direct fork/exec. Perhaps you can see if you can avoid the use of system() and try to use fork/exec in order to have more control (e.g. to clean up the memory in between the fork/exec calls.

Comment: When you say 'cpp application', do you mean an application written in C++? Do you mean that your script is run from within your application? The most likely reason for 'pipe call failed' in my estimation is that you have too many file descriptors open; you aren't closing some files (or pipes or sockets) when you could. Does the error come from the shell script itself, or from the C++ program running it via `system()`? When the `system()` call returns, the child has died; all its file descriptors are closed. There shouldn't be a problem in the application. Have you set FD_CLOEXEC appropriately?

Comment: @triplee - the link to useless use of grep is broken, here's a cached version: [Useless Use of grep | awk](http://archive.is/fBdSf)

Comment: @slm: Yeah, my bad; the old domain name was hijacked, but the canonical URL still works: http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep

Comment: @tripleee - ah, thanks, I couldn't find the source and was editing the ~24 Q's on SO that used this same link to a cached copy, change them to this one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the issue. I am using socket communication in my application. Some how some sockets were not closing properly.so after some time file descriptors will exhaust which is leading to the issue "pipe call failed" because pipe also uses descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any obvious issues with your script; the error messages does 'sound like' a ***system resource*** problem (and these values may vary considerably between systems.)  Some suggestions:

- Consider using 'fgrep' when special characters are involved and you need to negate possible shell variable munging (don't think that's a factor here, but just in case...)
- Check the 'limits' for the user/process you are running using ***ulimit -a***
- you could be 'consuming' more open files (guessing) than allowed OR it could be that the 'system' is having the issue (instead of the 'user process'); the 'real' problem could be some other process running at the same time is consuming the resource.
- If your system/user 'limits' are ok and Since you state that this is an 'infinite loop' then I will guess that you are spawning multiple processes instead of running only one.  Once you reach the 'hard limit' for *pipe* or *file-related* resources the script fails and you get a 'system error'.

  $ ulimit -a | awk '{printf "%3d | %s\n", NR, $0}'

> 1 | core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
>    2 | data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
>    3 | scheduling priority             (-e) 0
>    4 | file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
>    5 | pending signals                 (-i) 46232
>    6 | max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
>    7 | max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
>    **8 | open files                      (-n) 1024**
>    9 | pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
>   10 | POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
>   11 | real-time priority              (-r) 0
>   12 | stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
>   13 | cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
>   **14 | max user processes              (-u) 1024**
>   15 | virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
>   **16 | file locks                      (-x) unlimited**

Answer (score 2):

The error message "pipe call failed" means that there is no more free memory to allocate. 
As suggested by Dale, check the limits of your system using **ulimit -a** and verify in which way the **system** command is called: sequentially or in parallel.

Pipes have a size of 64KB starting form the kernel 2.6.11. Moreover, the system() command executes a command by calling **/bin/sh -c command** and returns after the command has been completed. Is not very efficient to call the **system** command 1000 times, so my advice is to add a *while* cycle inside your script to avoid weak performance (you can provide the number of iterations as a second argument).

Finally, it is a good practice to add a shebang (**#!/bin/sh**) as the first line of the script if it is intended to be run as an executable. This is not strictly necessary, because if the shebang is missing, the default shell (e.g. **/bin/sh**) is used.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOME_NETWORK_INTERFACE=eth0
echo "Generating list of MoCA device MACs..."
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "Error! Insufficient arguments. Format is $0 <output file path>"
        exit 1
fi

X=0
while [ $X -lt $2 ]
do
    arp -n -i $HOME_NETWORK_INTERFACE | grep "?" | awk '{print $4}' > $1
    X=`expr $X + 1`
done
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 2):

"alvits" has exactly pointed out the issue with using system command. Usually we try to implement the equivalent "C" code rather than using system command so as to avoid memory spikes. 
It seems that you are using a while loop into you C++ code and calling this script. Just try if you can run the script in while loop (resulting into only a single system call), redirect the o/p to a file and the read the file continuously for the desired result.